# Как реализовать метод добавить автора книги?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Created by dasha on 01/11/15.
 */
class Book {
    private String bookName;
    private int year;
    private Author author;

        public Book(String bookName, int year, Author author ) {
            this.bookName = bookName;
            this.year = year;
            this.author = author;
        }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.bookName+" ," + this.year+" " + this.author.toString();
    }

}




class Author {
    private String gender;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private  int phone;
    private String email;

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Author(String gender, String firstName, String lastName, int phone, String email ){
        this.gender = gender;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getGender()+" ," + this.getFirstName()+" " +this.getLastName()+ " ," +this.getPhone()+ " ,"+ this.getEmail();
    }


}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author author1 = new Author("m", "Joshua", "Bloch", 1111, "joshue@gmail.com");

        Book book1 = new Book("Java Core", 2012, author1);
        System.out.println(book1);

    }

}
```

Comment: если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, то нажмите на галочку слева от вопроса. Это отметит его, как "правильный ответ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
book1.setAuthor(new Author());
```

Comment: А так вообще не понятно что вас смущает в создании нужного вам метода.

Comment: Для простоты я изначально сделала,что у каждой книги может быть один автор. Сейчас хочу сделать массив  Author [] author ,добавлять новых авторов и перезаписывать их в новый массив, чтобы можно было неограниченое кол-во раз добавлять, а не строго по размеру массива.

Comment: В таком случае лучше пользовать списки, а не массивы. Списки могут динамически менять длинну. Так что пользуйте `ArrayList`, например

Comment: Тогда метод можно такой пользовать: `book1.addAuthor(new Author());`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.